# GIF images having transparent backgrounds after uploading shows black background?

Tags: joomla, gif, upload

I am using seyret component to upload my files. I uploaded a GIF the thumbnails it is extracting is having a blackbackground however the original upload is alright.

Comment: Uploading to where? A webpage you wrote? If so, what language is it written in and what libraries are you using?

Comment: Created with Photoshop by any chance?

Comment: i am using php joomla and joomla component is seyret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the thumbnail is dynamically created by the Joomla! extension?  Make sure you are saving the gif without transparency.